# Haskell: Point-free style

Tags: haskell, pointfree

Why does the first one fails while the latter one succeeds in compilation?

I expect `foo` and `foo'` are equivalent, that is, `foo'` is just a point-free function
of `foo`:

```
foo :: [a] -> [a] -> [(a,a)]
foo = map id . zip

foo' :: [a] -> [a] -> [(a,a)]
foo' a b = map id $ zip a b
```

But `foo` fails with following error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘[b0] -> [(a, b0)]’ with ‘[b]’
Expected type: [a] -> [b]
  Actual type: [a] -> [b0] -> [(a, b0)]
Relevant bindings include
  foo :: [a] -> [b] (bound at <interactive>:26:5)
Probable cause: ‘zip’ is applied to too few arguments
In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘zip’
In the expression: map id . zip
```

Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: try `(map id .) . zip`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the definition/type signature of `(.)` you see that its arguments are functions with a single parameter. But `zip` has two thus you have to supply at least one parameter to make it equivalent

```
foo a = map id . zip a
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do all functions in Haskell take one argument, don't they? `zip :: [a] -> ([b] -> [(a,b)])`

Comment: Aha. I can see. then `map` rejects function argument.

Comment: yes - the second part for map to work would have to have type signature of the shape `[a] -> [b -> (a,b)]`